# Animate only the newest section of a UIBezierPath (for a line graph)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, calayer

I'm building a simple `UIView` subclass that plots some data as a line graph. I'd like to animate the data points as they come in, but as a newcomer to `CAShapeLayer`, I feel there's got to be a better way than what I'm doing. I've read a few articles and put together some code loosely based on [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/).

Here's the code. Essentially it redraws the entire path every time new data are available, but only animates the new section (well, approximately).

```
let animationLayer = CALayer()

func setupDrawingLayer(){        
    pathLayer.frame = self.animationLayer.bounds
    pathLayer.bounds = self.animationLayer.bounds
    pathLayer.geometryFlipped = true
    pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    pathLayer.fillColor = nil
    pathLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
    self.animationLayer.addSublayer(pathLayer)        
}

func nextPoint(){ // This is called by a timer to simulate a new data point 
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(self.dataPoints[0])
    for i in 1...pointIndex{
        path.addLineToPoint(self.dataPoints[i])
    }
    pathLayer.path = path.CGPath
    pointIndex += 1

    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"strokeEnd")
    pathAnimation.duration = 0.5
    pathAnimation.fromValue = (Double(pointIndex) - 1.0) / Double(pointIndex)
    pathAnimation.toValue = 1.0
    self.pathLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey:"strokeEnd")
}
```

Also, as my `fromValue` weighting is just an approximation, it doesn't lead to a smooth animation. Ideally, I would think the approach in `nextPoint()` should be to animate only the newest section, then "save" it to the layer… but not sure how to approach that. Any pointers would be very welcome.

**UPDATE:**
This approach still recreates the path with each call of `nextPoint()` but at least the animation is now accurate:

```
func nextPoint(){
    let oldPath = pathLayer.path
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.moveToPoint(self.dataPoints[0])
    for i in 1...pointIndex{
        path.addLineToPoint(self.dataPoints[i])
    }
    pathLayer.path = path.CGPath
    pointIndex += 1

    let pathAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"path")
    pathAnimation.duration = 0.5
    pathAnimation.fromValue = oldPath
    pathAnimation.toValue = path.CGPath
    self.pathLayer.addAnimation(pathAnimation, forKey:"path")
}
```